# Python: passing an argument to a method within a class

Tags: python, class, methods

So for instance I have a class called Employee and I have a class method designed to raise the wage of an an Employee.
I just have issues actually getting my desired raise for the wage passed into the class method as an argument, it's baffling me.

Class module;

```
Class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, age):

        self.name = name.title()
        self.salary = salary
        self.age = age

    def raise_wage(self, raise):
        self.salary = self.salary + raise
```

main module;

```
def main():
    e1 = Employee("John Smith", 50000, 42)
    Employee.e1.raise_wage(500)
```

---

Passing that 500 in as an arguement is the issue, i get missing positional argument errors for the method etc.
How do I pass the argument to the class method?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: [`raise`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) is a reserved word in Python. You should choose a different name for that variable. Also you don't need to preface the instance with the class; this is sufficient: `e1.raise_wage(500)`

Comment: Also you have capitalized `Class` and used `Employee.e1.raise_wage` instead of `e1.raise_wage`. I'm assuming that in your own actual class you didn't have the `Class` or `raise` issues since those would raise `SyntaxError` and `AttributeError` otherwise.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
This includes the *full* error message and prior research to fix the obvious problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use `raise`. It is a reserved word.
2. Use `class` instead of `Class` to define a class.
3. Write `e1.raise_wage()` instead of `Employee.e1.raise_wage()`.

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, age):
        self.name = name.title()
        self.salary = salary
        self.age = age

    def raise_wage(self, amount):
        self.salary = self.salary + amount

e1 = Employee("John Smith", 50000, 42)
e1.raise_wage(500)

print(e1.salary) # output: 50500
```

Comment: That did the trick my friend, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**raise** is a reserved keyword used to raise an exception, change it to other name and it will work just fine.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_raise.asp

Answer (score 0):

raise is a reserved keyword in python for raising exception. use another name for that argument then it will work. And you already created object for Employee so no need to call function with class name again.